# Align generated maps and put captions

Tags: captions, alignment, karnaugh

I'm generating Karnaugh Maps with the `karnaugh-map` package.
How can I control the alignment of the maps and how can I put a caption under each map?

The result I'm getting now is this:

[image]

I want the maps to be one next the other and I want to be able to put a caption under each map or under both.

The maps are being generated with this code:

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}*[4][4][1][$a$ $b$][$c$ $d$]
    \minterms{0,2, 4,9,10}
    \implicant{4}{7}
\end{karnaugh-map}

\begin{karnaugh-map}*[4][4][1][$a$ $b$][$c$ $d$]
    \terms{0,2,8,10}{$A$}
    \implicantcorner[0]
\end{karnaugh-map}
```

I've tried with the `\caption` command but it does not compile.

Comment: Mostly you need to remove the blank line (new paragraph) between the two maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting the maps inside a `figure` and using the `subfigure` command. Here's the code:

```
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{karnaugh-map}*[4][4][1][$a$ $b$][$c$ $d$]
            \minterms{0,2, 4,9,10}
            \implicant{4}{7}
        \end{karnaugh-map}
        \caption{AAA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{karnaugh-map}*[4][4][1][$a$ $b$][$c$ $d$]
            \terms{0,2,8,10}{$A$}
            \implicantcorner[0]
        \end{karnaugh-map}
        \caption{Le celle contenenti $A$ sono adiacenti.}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

And here's the new result:

[image]

If someone has a better solution, please say so.

Comment: You could use a tabular to align the maps and captions separately.  I would have given a solution, but have no idea what package is needed for karnaugh-map.